# Read Blob Storage Azure Function HttpTrigger

Tags: azure-functions

Despite many posts in here or elsewhere I still have not found how to read a blob storage from an azure function.

I have as follows

[image]

Each of the above containers  has  a json file “customer.json”

Now I need to call my function and pass a parameter eg "london" to retrieve the london customer

```
Customer customer= await azureFunctionService.GetCustomer(“London”);
```

What should the function look like, ideally I would like to use input binding to read the json file from a function but any other way is fine too.

```
        [FunctionName("GetCustomer")]
        public static void Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            string inputBlobPath,
            [Blob("howDoIBuildPathIncludingtheparameter", 
                FileAccess.Read, Connection = "WhereDoIGetThis")] string json,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Not sure if anything is required here apart from logging when using input binding
            //
        }
```

Any suggestions?

many thanks

Comment: Are you using Azure Function 2 or greater

Comment: @maxspan Hi is version 3. Created by default I am using Visual studio 2019 16.5 to create the function.Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried the below code.
The following example is a C# function that uses a queue trigger and an input blob binding. The queue message contains the name of the blob, and the function logs the size of the blob.

```
[FunctionName("BlobInput")]
public static void Run(
    [QueueTrigger("myqueue-items")] string myQueueItem,
    [Blob("samples-workitems/{queueTrigger}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream myBlob,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"BlobInput processed blob\n Name:{myQueueItem} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} bytes");
```

}

Comment: I didnt bcse it was using "QueueTrigger" and not HttpTrigger and also in  my case what should I put "samples-workitems/{queueTrigger}" here  , how would you change it to fit my case. I need to undestand the syntaxt if you like

Comment: Yes please Replace QueueTrigger with Httptrigger

Comment: ok which i did in my question but what is the syntax in here [Blob("samples-workitems/{queueTrigger} and should there be a connection to the blob storage

Comment: obviously given that my blobstoragename =london and filename=customer.json  and  I do not want to hardcode then in the function how does the attribute reads it?

Comment: you need to pass it in Route value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210487/discussion-between-maxspan-and-developer9969).

Comment: I managed for now todo using code rather than inputbinding. my next challenge is how not to hardcode the function key in the app

Comment: Hi Mate would you like to have the solution With HttpTrigger and Blob storage.

Answer (score 4):

This Microsoft documentation gives a brief example of how to extract data from an `HttpTrigger` to populate the input binding path of a blob: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#json-payloads

As described, define the payload object separately and then use this type with the `HttpTrigger` attribute. The object properties are then available for reference in other input binding expressions.

```cs
public class BlobInfo
{
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}

public static class GetCustomer
{
    [FunctionName("GetCustomer")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] BlobInfo info,
        [Blob("{CityName}/customer.json", FileAccess.Read)] Stream blob,
        ILogger log)
    {
```

Call this function with a JSON payload specifying the required city name e.g. `curl http://localhost:7071/api/GetCustomer -d "{'CityName':'manchester'}"`.

This initialises the blob input parameter with the contents of the blob in a container named 'manchester' entitled 'customer.json'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid passing the parameter from request body, instead read the mapping parameter from query param, below snippet should help you. The Query reference helps you fetch the query parameters.

```
[Blob("{Query.container}/{Query.blobpath}", FileAccess.Read)] string jsonBlobStr
```

Instead of declaring jsonBlobStr as str, you could rather declare as Stream, so that whole file is not loaded onto memory.

Then call the HttpTrigger endpoint by passing the required parameters.

```
http://localhost:7071/api/GetCustomer?container=my-container&blobpath=path/to/customer.json
```